# Img src is undefined after addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I want to change a picture to a gif on mouse over, and revert it back on mouse out. But img src stays undefined after onmouseout, howerer it should be visible, because imgsrc array is an global varriable

Here is my code:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-oe-id] img');

var i;
var imgsrc=[];
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    imgsrc[i] = list[i].src;
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(event)
    {
     console.log(imgsrc[i]); // Here it is undefined
     this.src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/PfFtibPKBbQrK/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47b668e5062e9a561e681f23705e106d8d495b3915&rid=giphy.gif";
     });
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseout",function(event)
    {
      this.src=imgsrc[i]; // Here is the same thing
    });
}
```

Comment: This would be better to accomplish with the `:hover` CSS selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because let is brackes scope, better code will be :

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-oe-id] img');

for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    let image = list[i];
    let src = image.src;

    image.addEventListener("mouseover",function(event){
     console.log(src); 
     image.src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/PfFtibPKBbQrK/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47b668e5062e9a561e681f23705e106d8d495b3915&rid=giphy.gif";
    });
    image.addEventListener("mouseout",function(event){
      image.src=src; 
    });
}
```

Check it out and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is with `this`. Within an event listener, `this` represents the `event` not the object calling the event.

Change `this.src` to `list[i].src`

`this.src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/PfFtibPKBbQrK/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47b668e5062e9a561e681f23705e106d8d495b3915&rid=giphy.gif";`

to

`list[i].src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/PfFtibPKBbQrK/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47b668e5062e9a561e681f23705e106d8d495b3915&rid=giphy.gif";`

change
`this.src=imgsrc[i];`

to

`list[i].src=imgsrc[i];`

Comment: This is critical but the code will still not work correctly because `i` will be `3` by the time the handlers are called. A `for` scoped loop variable (`let`/`const`), using `.forEach`, or creating an event listener factory taking the index as a parameter will be required.